# C# MongoDB Update / Upsert List<Object> to Collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, list, collections, multiple-instances

I was searching for a way to Update / Upsert in MongoDB a List of items to a MongoDB collection.

Is there any way to do it or I have to use a loop to update the items one by one?

P.S: The problem is not making a method that would do the Job (one by one) but I want to avoid too much iterations with the MongoDB database.

Here's the method that I'm currently using:

```
    public static void UpdateAll()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://server_ip:27017");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("M_PROJECT");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<Product>("products");

        //Config.Products is a List<Product> that was previously retrieved from the same collection in MongoDB
        foreach(Product product in Config.Products)
        {
            var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(p => p.ID, product.ID);
            var update = Builders<Product>.Update.Set("Name", product.Name).Set("Price", 20);
            collection.UpdateOne(filter, update, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true });
        }
    }
```

And maybe without specifying every Field/Property that I want to update, but just applying the class instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a bulk replace like so:

```cs
    var models = new List<WriteModel<Product>>();

    foreach (var product in Config.Products)
    {
        if (product.ID == null) product.ID = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();        

        var upsert = new ReplaceOneModel<Product>(
                        filter: Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(p => p.ID, product.ID),
                        replacement: product)
        { IsUpsert = true };

        models.Add(upsert);
    }

    collection.BulkWrite(models);
```

the thing to note here is that it will completely overwrite the data stored in the db with the data from your product class instances. but i think you'd be okay cause you said the products are retrieved from the same collection.

this is what my library [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/master/MongoDB.Entities/DB.Save.cs#L90) does internally to achieve `products.Save()`

Comment: this was just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use UpdateMany() instead of UpdateOne().  See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-csharp-and-mongodb--update-operation and https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_UpdateMany__1.htm for more details.

Comment: I mean if I can update every item in the list in a different document in the collection