# Multi Threaded C# Application - MongoDB misses records during Insert with no error

Tags: c#, mongodb, multithreading

I'm working on Mongo Db C# Driver version 2.0.1.27 and Mongo Db version 3.0.

Our Aim is to insert huge number of documents into the MongoDb Collection using "Insert" method.

Our Architecture calls this Add method multiple times for each thread.
Below is the Add method:

```
public bool Add(CallContext context, FileQueueEntity entity)
        {
            bool bResult = false;
            // This logic is to prevent duplicate file.
            // Consider new algorithm if supporting other files types
            bResult = Delete(context, entity);
            if (context.ErrorList.Count == 0)
            {
                var server = GetMongoServer();
                try
                {
                    var database = GetMongoDatabase(server);
                    var collection = database.GetCollection<FileQueueEntity>("QueueCollection");

                    entity.BaseMeta = null;
                    entity.IsNew = false;
                    collection.Insert(entity);
                    context.AddToUpdatedList(entity);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    bResult = false;
                    context.AddError(ErrorSeverity.System, "DataAccess.AddFileQueue", GetThreadExceptionMessage(ex));
                }
                finally
                {
                }
            }
            return bResult;
        }
```

Below is the Get MongoDatabase Method:

```
private MongoDatabase GetMongoDatabase(MongoServer mongoServer)
        {
            return mongoServer.GetDatabase(mConnectionBuilder.InitialCatalog);
        }
```

Below is the one for GetMongoServer

```
private MongoServer GetMongoServer()
        {
            System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(_lock);
            try
            {
                if (_mongoServer != null)
                {
                    return _mongoServer;
                }

                DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
                var aDatabase = factory.Create("ConnectionStringName");
                mConnectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(aDatabase.ConnectionString);
                var credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential(mConnectionBuilder.InitialCatalog, mConnectionBuilder.UserID, mConnectionBuilder.Password);
                MongoServerSettings databaseSettings = new MongoServerSettings();

                var connectionStrings = mConnectionBuilder.DataSource.Split(',');

                if (connectionStrings != null && connectionStrings.Count() > 1)
                {
                    string ipAddress = connectionStrings[0];
                    int portNumber = Convert.ToInt32(connectionStrings[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    databaseSettings.Credentials = new[] { credential };
                    databaseSettings.Server = new MongoServerAddress(ipAddress, portNumber);
                }

                _mongoServer = new MongoServer(databaseSettings);
                return _mongoServer;
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }

        }
```

and this is called in this way:

```
foreach (var n in entities)
{
    Add(n);
}
```

The Foreach loop is called for every instance separately.

The problem is that we are seeing that all the files are not reaching the db as every time there are 
random files which are missing from the table.

The entity that we are sending is very light(hardly 400-500bytes).
The Number of files will be 2000-5000 max which will be cleared on daily basis.
So the maximum storage will not be exceeded in this case

For Example:

```
Thread 1: 50 files  -   Random 48 files are inserted
Thread 2: 80 files  -   Random 75 files are inserted
Thread 3: 70 files  -   Random 60 files are inserted
Thread 4: 60 files  -   Random 59 files are inserted
```

Are we missing any Mongo Configuration as it is not throwing any exception and fails silently to insert the records,
Which is a bit strange.

The response we are getting duing insert is

```
Response: { "ok" : 1, "n" : NumberLong(0) }
```

It is observed that all the time random files from each of the thread are failing every time.

Can any one help me on this? Are we missing any MongoDB configuration?

Comment: What is `Delete` doing?

Comment: @fildor To prevent the duplicate record, I first delete the record.

Comment: Sooo, you 1) Open DB connection, delete an entity, close connection (seemingly), 2) Open another connection, insert the same entity, close connection 3) -> On multiple threads ...right?

Comment: @Fildor Yes! Thanks for pointing the Delete operation. That operation opens the connection, delete and close it. After that Add operation open the connection, add and close the connection. This should be handled under single connection, will update it.

Answer (score 0):

couple of points for consideration:

1. `IMongoColleciton` can be retrieved once and stored as static/singleton. that is the [recommended pattern](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/getting_started/quick_tour/#mongoclient).
2. deletion is redundant. use `collection.ReplaceOne(e => e.Id == entity.Id, entity);`
3. better yet, use [bulk replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60094284/c-sharp-mongodb-update-upsert-listobject-to-collection/60095707#60095707) with batches of about 50 to 100 entities in each iteration or thread.
4. try to update to the latest server and driver. So many good changes have occurred since v2.0

Comment: I will try this solution and will update the findings. Thanks.